# Numpy/Scipy : solving several least squares with the same design matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy, least-squares

I face a least square problem that i solve via `scipy.linalg.lstsq(M,b)`, where :

- `M` has shape `(n,n)`
- `b` has shape `(n,)`

The issue is that i have to solve it a bunch of time for different `b`'s. How can i do something more efficient ? I guess that `lstsq` does a lot of things independently of the value of `b`.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case your linear system is well-determined, I'll store `M` LU decomposition and use it for all the `b`'s individually or simply do one solve call for 2d-array `B` representing the horizontally stacked `b`'s, it really depends on your problem here but this is globally the same idea. Let's suppose you've got each `b` one at a time, then:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lstsq, lu_factor, lu_solve, svd, pinv

# as you didn't specified any practical dimensions
n = 100
# number of b's
nb_b = 10

# generate random n-square matrix M
M = np.random.rand(n**2).reshape(n,n)

# Set of nb_b of right hand side vector b as columns
B = np.random.rand(n*nb_b).reshape(n,nb_b)

# compute pivoted LU decomposition of M
M_LU = lu_factor(M)
# then solve for each b
X_LU = np.asarray([lu_solve(M_LU,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
```

but if it is under or over-determined, you need to use [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq) as you did:

```
X_lstsq = np.asarray([lstsq(M,B[:,i])[0] for i in range(nb_b)])
```

or simply store the pseudo-inverse `M_pinv` with [pinv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv.html#scipy.linalg.pinv) (built on lstsq) or [pinv2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pinv2.html#scipy.linalg.pinv2) (built on SVD):

```
# compute the pseudo-inverse of M
M_pinv = pinv(M)
X_pinv = np.asarray([np.dot(M_pinv,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
```

or you can also do the work by yourself, as in `pinv2` for instance, just store the SVD of `M`, and solve this manually:

```
# compute svd of M
U,s,Vh = svd(M)

def solve_svd(U,s,Vh,b):
    # U diag(s) Vh x = b <=> diag(s) Vh x = U.T b = c
    c = np.dot(U.T,b)
    # diag(s) Vh x = c <=> Vh x = diag(1/s) c = w (trivial inversion of a diagonal matrix)
    w = np.dot(np.diag(1/s),c)
    # Vh x = w <=> x = Vh.H w (where .H stands for hermitian = conjugate transpose)
    x = np.dot(Vh.conj().T,w)
    return x

X_svd = np.asarray([solve_svd(U,s,Vh,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
```

which all give the same result if checked with `np.allclose` (unless the system is not well-determined resulting in the LU direct approach failure). Finally in terms of performances:

```
%timeit M_LU = lu_factor(M); X_LU = np.asarray([lu_solve(M_LU,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

%timeit X_lstsq = np.asarray([lstsq(M,B[:,i])[0] for i in range(nb_b)])
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop

%timeit M_pinv = pinv(M); X_pinv = np.asarray([np.dot(M_pinv,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
100 loops, best of 3: 8.64 ms per loop

%timeit U,s,Vh = svd(M); X_svd = np.asarray([solve_svd(U,s,Vh,B[:,i]) for i in range(nb_b)])
100 loops, best of 3: 5.68 ms per loop
```

Nevertheless, it's up to you to check these with appropriate dimensions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I am guessing you mean to compute the equation `Mx=b` through `scipy.linalg.lstsq(M,b)` for different arrays (`b0, b1, b2..`). If that is the case you could just parallelize the process with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. The documentation for this is fairly simple and can help python run multiple scipy solvers at once.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i am doing, and i was wandering if there is not a better solution, since the design of the least square problem (`M`) does not change, maybe a part of the computation could be done once and for all `b`'s.

Comment: I am unsure if I understand still, but I don't think the solver is computing anything non-trivial independently of `b`.

Comment: I think you understood. This is sad :(

Answer (score 0):

You can factorize `M` into either QR or SVD products and find the lsq solution manually.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.linalg.lstsq` has the built in ability to calculate the least squares solution to Ax=b for multiple different RHS (e.g. b0, b1, b2). To compute solutions for k different RHS, for the parameter `b` pass in a (m, k)-sized matrix. From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) for the parameter `b`:

> ...If b is two-dimensional, the least-squares solution is calculated for each of the K columns of b.